# android studio about inserting event on own mobile calendar

Tags: android

the programme runs with error. however, the event doesnt insert into my own mobile's calendar. does anyone know the reason about that?? my mobile is pentech a880. Or there is another method to insert the events?

```
package com.example.lean.myapplication;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_fragment);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(View v) {
                                      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                      startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                                  }
                              }

    );
    addToCalendar(getApplicationContext(), "hello","2015/10/10 10:05:33" );
}


    public static void addToCalendar(Context oContext, final String title, final String eventStartDate)
    {
        String eventUriString = null;

        long startDate = new Date(eventStartDate).getTime();
        long endDate = new Date(eventStartDate).getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60; // For next 1hr
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

        ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13)
        {
            eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";

            eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1);
            eventValues.put("title", title);
            eventValues.put("description", "");
            eventValues.put("eventLocation", "");

            eventValues.put("dtstart", startDate);
            eventValues.put("dtend", endDate);
            eventValues.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
            eventValues.put("eventStatus", "");
            eventValues.put("visibility", 3);
            eventValues.put("transparency", 0);
            eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1);

            Uri eventUri = oContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), eventValues);
            long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());

            String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";

            ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

            reminderValues.put("event_id", eventID);
            reminderValues.put("minutes", 5);
            reminderValues.put("method", 1);

            oContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);

        }
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 )
        {
            eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startDate);
            eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endDate);
            eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
            eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "");
            eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3);
            eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

            oContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), eventValues);
        }

        Toast.makeText(oContext, "Event Created on : " + startDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you didn't ask for the permissions

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"...>
         ...
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
         ...
     </manifest>
```

Comment: i find the value startDate= 1444600800000 ,,, what does that mean,, i suspect its the format the date causing the problem

Comment: @rayray Coding 101: Read the documentation. You can literally just see what that number represents by a simple google search that takes 5 seconds.